# In C/C++, return type of main() can be int/void but in JAVA it can only be void why?

Tags: java

In C/C++, return type of main() can be int/void but in JAVA it can only be void why ?

Comment: [`main` in C/C++ must always return `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)